# Struggling to find the error in my word-finding code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that will check if an inputted word can be made with the letters of another word.

So far, I have:

```
def is_made_from(wordA,wordB):
for l in wordA:
    if wordA.count(l) <= wordB.count(l):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I'm not sure if what I mean is being translated to code. The loop goes through every letter in wordA to check if wordB has at least the same quantity of that letter as in wordA. However, when I run a free trials, the code seems to work when it should work but it also works when it shouldn't work. For example, if I made wordA == 'whiter' and wordB == 'white', it would return True, despite wordB not having the 'r.'

Comment: Your code returns from the function at the first character (because either the number is equal and you return True, or it's different and you return False) but never looks at the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you return True even if only the 1st letter matches, because if the code enters the if on the first iteration, it returns True and the loop is exited.

You are looking for something like this

```
def is_made_from(wordA,wordB):
    for l in wordA:
        if not wordA.count(l) <= wordB.count(l):
            return False
    return True
```

It works the other way round.

Comment: @ChartererSling Excellent. That's how I had it in my head, but I made a mistake typing it out

Answer (score 0):

Pedantically-awesome version:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_made_from(first, second):
   return len(Counter(first) - Counter(second)) == 0
```

(this honestly suffers from being "too clever"; calling `.count()` in a loop is probably more readable and performs just fine unless your words are tens of thousands of characters long)